# How to clone existing index data from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

I want to clone an existing index data (from day 1 to now) from elastic search to another elastic search in new server. I read some references and know i can take a snapshot and restore it. Is it a best way to clone the index data? and the snapshot includes the data from day 1 to now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are meant to be used for :

1. Backups & recovery
2. Data export -> import

Using a snapshot for migrating data b/w 2 ES clusters **are fine as long as both the clusters are on the same version of ES.**